# Celebrity visa stamping

Tags: visas, air-travel

Do celebrities and other VIPs have to appear for Visa interviews and such if they have to travel to a country which would require a visa based on their citizenship? Are there easier ways to get the Visa/ get the interviews and such waived if you are a well known media personality?

Comment: There may be things like [UK Super Premium Service](https://www.gov.uk/ukvi-premium-service-centres/use-the-super-premium-service) offered for a large fee.  But I think this is too broad if you're asking about every country at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, from a legal point of view they are normal people just like you and me. Unless they have a non-ordinary passport, they have to go through the normal procedure.

There might be easier procedures for artists having shows or sportsmen participating in competitions in some countries though.